# SQLFORM.grid() left join output

Tags: web2py

I'm struggling with web2py and SQLFORM.grid.

What I want to do is the following:

I have three database tables: items, tag and the cross table itemtag.

One item can have several tags and one tag can belong to several items.

What I have so far:

```
fields = [db.items.id, db.items.title, db.items.rating, db.tag.title]
left = [db.itemtag.on(db.items.id==db.itemtag.item_id), db.tag.on(db.itemtag.tag_id==db.tag.id)]
items = SQLFORM.grid(db.items, left=left, orderby=[db.items.title], fields=fields, create=False, editable=False, details=False, showbuttontext=False, paginate=50, links = [lambda row: A(I(_class="icon-edit"),_href=URL("default","item_edit",args=[row.items.id]))])
```

Now the SQLFORM.grid produces a grid with all items. But unfortunately if an item have several tags it have several rows in the grid. Like this:

```
ID | item  | tag
1  | item1 | tag 1
1  | item1 | tag 2
1  | item1 | tag 3
2  | item2 | tag 2
....
```

Now I'm searching for an groupby function for SQLFORM.grid. What I want is the following:

```
ID | item  | tag
1  | item1 | tag1, tag2, tag3
2  | item2 | tag
```

I look forward to any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do a query like that using the grid (or using the DAL in general). As an alternative, you can use the `links` argument to generate a custom column that includes the list of tags for each item:

```
def taglist(row):
    tags = db((db.itemtag.item_id == row.id) &
              (db.itemtag.tag_id == db.tag.id)).select()
    return ', '.join(tag.name for tag in tags)

items = SQLFORM.grid(db.items, orderby=[db.items.title], 
    fields=[db.items.id, db.items.title, db.items.rating],
    create=False, editable=False, details=False,
    showbuttontext=False, paginate=50,
    links = [lambda row: A(I(_class="icon-edit"), _href=URL("default",
                           "item_edit", args=[row.items.id])),
             dict(heading='Tags', body=taglist)])
```

An item in the `links` list can be a dict with `header` and `body` keys, in which case it will be displayed in a separate column with the specified header.

Note, this method is somewhat inefficient, as it will result in an additional query for each row in the grid in order to retrieve the list of tags for that row.

Another option is to use a virtual field (only very recent versions of web2py display virtual fields in grids):

```
def taglist(row):
    tags = db((db.itemtag.item_id == row.items.id) &
              (db.itemtag.tag_id == db.tag.id)).select()
    return ', '.join(tag.name for tag in tags)

db.items.tags = Field.Virtual('tags', taglist)
```

Once you have defined the "tags" virtual field for the `db.items` table, you can display it in the grid like any other field. Note, the definition of the `taglist()` function in this case is slightly different than the original above -- when defining virtual fields, it is necessary to refer to the table and field within the row object, so the query includes `row.items.id` rather than just `row.id`.

Note, like the `links` solution, the virtual field alternative also results in a separate query per row of the grid.

The benefit of using a virtual field is that once defined, it can be used in other contexts as well. However, keep in mind that its values will be filled in whenever you select records from the `db.items` table, so if you don't need the list of tags in other contexts, you might want to define the virtual field conditionally (e.g., only define it in the controller where you need it) in order to avoid unnecessary database queries.

UPDATE: Another option to consider is replacing the many-to-many database model with a `list:reference` type field in the `db.items` table to store a list of references to the `db.tag` table (see [example](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#list:<type>,-and-contains)). As long as you set the `format` attribute of the `db.tag` table to the tag name (or explicitly set the `represent` attribute of the `list:reference` field to display the tag names), you will get a comma-separated list of tag names for that field in the grid.

This method still requires a query per row to get the tag names, but that query doesn't involve a join. The limitation of using a `list:reference` field, though, is that operations requiring aggregation over tags (e.g., building a tag cloud) can be less efficient because you no longer have fully normalized data.

Note, none of the methods described above allow for searching the tags within the grid. For searchability, the simplest approach is to use a `list:string` type field in `db.items` to store the tag. This makes it even more difficult to do operations on tags, though, as there is no longer a tag table with a single record per tag (instead, tags are repeated among the records of the `db.items` table).

Another option might be to retain the many-to-many model but add a [computed field](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#Computed-fields) in `db.items` to store a list of tag names derived from the many-to-many relation. This computed field would display in the grid and be searchable. You would probably also want to add `.after_insert` and `.after_update` [callbacks](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#before-and-after-callbacks) to the `db.itemtag` table that would automatically updated the `db.items` computed field whenever `db.itemtag` inserts/updates are made.

Finally, you could create custom grid search functionality. `SQLFORM.grid` takes a `search_widget` argument for implementing a custom search widget in the UI, and the `searchable` argument can be a callable object that takes the search widget keywords submission and produces a subquery to filter the records.

For help with these more advanced options, ask on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/web2py).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try it out now and will feed back if it works for me. One question at that: When I define a virtual field, is it possible to use the search functionality from SQLFORM.grid()?

Comment: The solution with the virtual field works like a charm. Thanks again :) The only thing that is not possible is to search items by tag name in SQLFORM.grid(). If there is any solution, I would be happy to hear about it.

Comment: Updated the answer with some more options, though there isn't currently a particularly easy way to make the tags searchable in the grid (I think the main options would be using a `list:string` field, a computed field, or implementing custom search functionality).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I have to try this out and read more about the suggested solutions. Many, many thanks again :)